# Why dynamic closure(closure as trait object) becomes unusable after putting behind Rc<RefCell<T>>?

Tags: rust, closures, reference-counting, interior-mutability

I need to put closures behind `<Rc<RefCell<T>>` for some reason:

1. multiple references to closure;
2. closure can modify environment(interior mutability);
3. closure is better stored as trait object because eventually I want to put references inside a vector.

However, closures become unusable when stored as trait object.

Here is an example. To simply, variable `closure` doesn't mutate environment. In my own use case, I do need mutate environment.

```rust
type Handler = FnMut(&mut u32);

let closure: rc::Rc<cell::RefCell<Handler>> = rc::Rc::new(cell::RefCell::new(|x: &mut u32|{
// would work if above line is:
// let closure: = rc::Rc::new(cell::RefCell::new(|x: &mut u32|{
    *x = 3;
}));

let mut y = 0u32;

let cc = closure.borrow_mut();

cc(&mut y);
```

I know that it would work if I remove the type contraint on variable `closure`. But that way I lost the ability to put similar closures inside vec.

Is there a way to use closure behind `<Rc<RefCell<T>>`? Or is there other alternative in rust to meet the 3 requirements I listed?

Comment: You don't *need* `FnMut` here (and hence don't need to borrow mutably or even use `RefCell` at all), since there are no variables moved into the closure so it doesn't have its own state. You only have a mutable parameter, but the closure itself doesn't mutate.

Comment: To apply the answer in the duplicate I linked, you just need to change the second to last line to `let cc = &mut *closure.borrow_mut();`

Comment: You are right. That solves my problem. Thank you Wesley.